# selenium element not interactable even after element is present

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a Java code for selenium and I'm trying to change the country on my website using selenium, somehow the code is running fine and the steps are executed as per the command line but when I check the execution of the test, the country isn't changed.

This is the code i have written

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class simpleCartFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/manavmehta/Desktop/squareoffSeleniumProjects/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://release.squareoffnow.com/");
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1440, 789));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//        selectCountry.usaCountry(driver);
        System.out.println("step 1 start");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".selected-flag > .iti-flag")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@id='iti-item-us'])")).click();
        System.out.println("flag clicked pleaseeeeeeeee");
        System.out.println("step 1 done");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Products")).click();
//        driver.quit();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".store-buy-pro-button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pro-twinpack-button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".whole-purchase-button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".productAvailability > .click-button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".giftpackSubmit")).click();
        System.out.println("button not clicked");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".checkout-anchor")).click();
        System.out.println("button clicked");
        details.addressDetails(driver);
//        driver.findElement(By.id("name1")).click();
//        driver.findElement(By.id("name1")).sendKeys("tester");
//        driver.findElement(By.id("name2")).sendKeys("tester");
//        driver.findElement(By.id("phone1")).sendKeys("13024025552");
//        driver.findElement(By.id("email1")).sendKeys("XYZ@GMAIL.COM");
//        driver.findElement(By.id("address1")).sendKeys("--");
////        driver.findElement(By.id("state1")).sendKeys("California");
//        driver.findElement(By.id("zipcode1")).sendKeys("12085");
//        driver.findElement(By.id("city1")).sendKeys("Guilderland Center");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".secure-pic")).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Field-numberInput")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Field-numberInput")).sendKeys("4242 4242 4242 4242");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Field-expiryInput")).sendKeys("04 / 22");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Field-expiryInput")).sendKeys("04 / 44");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Field-cvcInput")).sendKeys("323");

//        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

what I want to do is click on the flag, and change the country from the dropdown.
[image]

I did a check to find if the element is present, the value came as true. I also added implicit wait of 30 seconds!!
the issue is that the element is not interactable

Comment: seems like you're missing the ".click()" method here: driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@id='iti-item-us'])"));

Comment: yes you were right I checked it and adding the click() helped but it seems my element is not interactable, even after being present

Comment: adding webdriverwaits will probably help here... use expected condition of element to be clickable.